# Add return of stock data with function Delt() to a list of dataframe

Tags: r, list, lapply, finance, quantmod

I have a list of data frames with stock data and want to add a new column with return of the stock price to each data frame in the list. The data frames looks as:

```
        ABB.ST.Open ABB.ST.High ABB.ST.Low ABB.ST.Close ABB.ST.Volume ABB.ST.Adjusted       Date
    1         166.4       167.4      165.5        166.0        944525        162.1181 2015-01-02
    2         165.6       166.6      164.4        164.4       1013670        160.5555 2015-01-05
    3         161.2       161.6      159.1        159.1       2546062        155.3794 2015-01-07
    4         160.3       163.3      159.2        163.0       1946157        159.1882 2015-01-08
    5         162.8       162.8      160.0        160.6       1885969        156.8444 2015-01-09
    6         161.5       162.6      160.6        161.1       1795966        157.3327 2015-01-12
    7         159.8       160.6      158.3        160.0       2445040        156.2584 2015-01-13
    Delt.1.arithmetic
1                  NA
2       -0.0066959806
3       -0.0127628163
4        0.0168292916
5       -0.0002389207
6        0.0141549696
7       -0.0044953302
```

This goes on down till the date od today, i.e. approx 1300 rows.

Now want to add the return of the first column `ABB.ST.Open` with the function `Delt` from package `quantmod`.

This code work when I apply it to just the data frame, outside the list:

```
ABB.ST$Return <- Delt(ABB.ST[,1])
```

But how do I add this column to all data frame in a `list`?

My list name is `master_df` and I have tried this code, but it does not work...

```
Return <- function(x){
  master_df[[x]]$Return <- Delt(master_df[[x]][,1])
} 

test2 <- lapply(master_df, Return(x))
```

UPDATE:

I have data.frame in the list, where my list name is `master_df`, this is my code where I download data from yahoo finance:

`as.matrix(LargeCapOMXS[,7])` is my list of symbols names from yahoo

```
Stocklist <- as.matrix(LargeCapOMXS[,7]) #get names of stocks
master_df <- list() #create list to fill with data

for(i in seq(length(Stocklist))){ #loop to fill list with downloaded stock data, by company
  Stockindex = Stocklist[i]
  getSymbols(Stockindex, src="yahoo", from="2015-01-01", to="2020-01-01", verbose = TRUE)
  master_df[[i]] <- as.data.frame(get(Stockindex))
  master_df[[i]]$Date = row.names(master_df[[i]])
  row.names( master_df[[i]]) = NULL
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a list of data.frames or a list of xts objects? How did you create your list? Add the quantmod code to your question for 2 stocks to show how you got where you are.

Comment: Thank you phiver, I have now added my loop to how my list looks like now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is some code to get the data from yahoo, into a list and add the Delt column to each xts object. No need for creating data.frames. You can always do this later.

```
library(quantmod)

stock_list <- c("ABB", "ABT")

master_df <- lapply(stock_list, getSymbols, from = "2015-01-01", to = "2020-01-01", auto.assign = FALSE)
names(master_df) <- stock_list

# need to merge the xts with the outcome of Delt as Delt only returns 1 column
# function Op selects the open column.
master_df <- lapply(master_df, function(x) merge(x, Delt(Op(x))))
```

Or using tidyquant if you want a giant data.frame.

```
library(tidyquant)
library(dplyr)

master_df_tq <- tq_get(stock_list)
master_df_tq <- master_df_tq %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_mutate(select = open,
            mutate_fun = Delt)
```

Comment: Thanks phiver! I think your code easier to adapt, I am trying to learn more about the quantmod package. Seems very useful for this type of data.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the problem with the following for loop:

```
for(i in seq(length(master_df))){
  master_df[[i]]$Return <- Delt(master_df[[i]][,1])
}
```

Does anyone have an idea to use an apply function? this for loop is fairly fast, but for curiosity.